# How to update a Vue "ref" with Firebase "onSnapshot" listener values?

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-composition-api

I have a Vue composable that uses a Firebase `onSnapshot` listener.

When data changes on that listener I want it to update a `ref` named `documentsArray`.

When I console.log the `documentsArray` *inside* the `onSnapshot` function it seems to be working because it contains an array of values. But when I console.log *outside* the `onSnapshot` function the array is empty.

Why is this happening?

The console.log *outside* the `onSnapshot` function should also contain the array of values.

Here is my composable (I am using TypeScript):

```
import { ref, Ref, watchEffect } from "vue";
import { projectFirestore } from "@/firebase/config";
import {
  collection,
  query,
  orderBy,
  onSnapshot,
  DocumentData,
  Timestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

interface Document {
  id: string;
  message: string;
  name: string;
  createdAt: Timestamp;
}

const getCollection = (
  collectionString: string
): {
  documentsArray: Ref<Document[] | null>;
  error: Ref<string | null>;
} => {
  const documentsArray = ref<Document[] | null>(null);
  const error = ref<string | null>(null);
  const colRef = collection(projectFirestore, collectionString);
  const colRefOrdered = query(colRef, orderBy("createdAt"));

  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    colRefOrdered,
    (snap) => {
      const results: Document[] = [];
      snap.docs.forEach((doc: DocumentData) => {
        doc.data().createdAt && //Ensures the server timestamp has been added
          results.push({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
          });
      });
      documentsArray.value = results;
      console.log("documentsArray.value inside snapshot", documentsArray.value); //<-- This works. It prints an array of documents.
      error.value = null;
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
      documentsArray.value = null;
      error.value = "could not fetch data";
    }
  );
  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => {
      unsubscribe();
    });
  });
  console.log("documentsArray.value outside snapshot", documentsArray.value); //<-- This does not work. It prints an empty array.
  return { documentsArray, error };
};

export default getCollection;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the `onSnapshot` callback is run asynchronously (after running the code outside the callback), in order to see the changes outside function you've to create a watcher to see that changes:

```
import import { ref, Ref, watchEffect, watch } from "vue";

....
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
    colRefOrdered,
    (snap) => {
      ...
  );

watch(documentsArray,(newVal,oldVal){
  console.log("documentsArray.value outside snapshot", documentsArray.value);

},{deep:true})
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful for pointing me in the right direction. But the real reason I wanted the outside console.log to work was because the `getCollection` composable was returning `documentsArray` with a `null` value. So how do reconfigure the composable to use `watch` and return an updated array? I.e. when calling this composable in another file via `const { documentsArray, error } = getCollection("messages");` I want `documentsArray` to contain a value.

Comment: @TinyTiger your composable returns the `documentsArray` which is reactive, so you can use a `watch` or `computed` outside, the `console.log` at the end though will only be executed once and at this point the array is still null.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working using the code you provided above! But I used the `watch` in the file that was calling the composable. Much appreciated for the help :)